# QFileSystemModel -- Detecting empty folder (with 'AllDirs' filter)?

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt4, qtruby

I'm using Qt 4.6 within Ruby (via QtRuby) and am trying to make a generic Directory Selection Dialog which displays a small "loading" glyph whilst the file system is being queried and the Directory Tree (QTreeView) is being updated.

**UPDATE**: I must say that the animation doesn't work as expected, is there another way of detecting these events (loading, loaded) ? See "On another note" below.

I have managed to connect the "new directories loaded" event via the `rowsInserted` Signal of the used QFileSystemModel, works quite fine. I'm also able to catch the "loading new directories" event via the `rowsAboutToBeInserted` signal. Yet the animation I'm trying to play (a simple animated GIF to indicate progress, loaded within a QMovie) is getting played **even if** the directory which has been 'expanded' is empty. Here is the code I am using :

```
# FileSystemModel extension which shows a 'busy' animation
# in a given Qt::Label
class FileSystemModelEx < Qt::FileSystemModel

  # Slot declarations
  slots "handle_ready(QModelIndex, int, int)"
      slots "handle_busy(QModelIndex, int, int)"

  # Parametrised constructor, initializes fields
  def initialize(p_parent, p_label, p_busy_icon, p_ready_icon)

      # Call superclass constructor
      super(p_parent)

      # Set instance vars
      @label = p_label
      @busy_icon = p_busy_icon
      @ready_icon = p_ready_icon

      # Connect 'finished loaded' event
      Qt::Object.connect(self,
                        SIGNAL('rowsAboutToBeInserted(QModelIndex, int, int)'),
                        self,
                        SLOT('handle_busy(QModelIndex, int, int)'))

      # Connect 'loading' event
      Qt::Object.connect(self, 
                        SIGNAL('rowsInserted(QModelIndex, int, int)'),
                        self,
                        SLOT('handle_ready(QModelIndex, int, int)'))
  end

  # Loading finished event, changes icon state to ready
  def handle_ready(p_index, p_start, p_end)
      set_icon(false)   

      puts "    done - loaded #{rowCount(p_index)} folders"
  end

  # Loading started event, changes icon state to busy
  def handle_busy(p_index, p_start, p_end)
      set_icon(true)

      path = fileInfo(p_index).canonicalFilePath
    puts "Loading . . . path = '#{path}'"
  end

  # Overriden start loading event
  def fetchMore(p_index)
      handle_busy(p_index, nil, nil)
      super(p_index)
  end

  # Utility method, switches icons, depending on a given state
  def set_icon(p_busy) 
      movie = (p_busy ? @busy_icon : @ready_icon)
      @label.setMovie(movie)
      movie.start
  end   

end # class FileSystemModelEx
```

**My question would be**: How can I keep the animation from playing, if the loaded folder is empty? One cannot filter the empty directories beforehand, isn't that so?

**On another note**, is there another way of implementing such 'loading' / 'loaded' event handlers, other than that described above? I've looked around the signals, virtuals (`fetchMore` and `canFetchMore`, to no avail), [scanned the source](http://www.qt.gitorious.org/qt/dfaures-clone/blobs/2b13dc93d406040d5f62ca57b44969b484370f87/src/gui/dialogs/qfilesystemmodel.cpp) yet I cannot reach the call which sends the thread on its quest of retrieving more files. Overriding `event` or `timerEvent` doesn't help.

For completion's sake, here is the QFileSystemModel I'm using as well:

```
# Creates a FileSystemModel which display folders only
def create_model
    @model = FileSystemModelEx.new(self, 
                @form.iconPlaceholderDir, 
                @loading_icon, @folder_icon)

    @model.setReadOnly(true)
    @model.setFilter(Qt::Dir::NoDotAndDotDot | Qt::Dir::AllDirs)
    @model.setRootPath(Qt::Dir.rootPath)


    @form.shellTreeView.setModel(@model)
end
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!
I can provide further details if the need arises, no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try hooking up the model's [`directoryLoaded(const QString&)`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qfilesystemmodel.html#directoryLoaded) slot. It signals when the directory has been fully processed.

Sample app with qt4-ruby (2.1.0) build againts Ruby 1.8.7 and Qt 4.7.3

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w
require 'Qt4'

class MyObject < Qt::Object
    slots "mySlot(QString)"
    def mySlot(path)
        print "Done loading ", path, "\n"
    end
end

a = Qt::Application.new(ARGV)
m = Qt::FileSystemModel.new
v = Qt::TreeView.new
m.setRootPath("/")
v.setModel(m)
o = MyObject::new
Qt::Object.connect(m, SIGNAL('directoryLoaded(QString)'), o, SLOT('mySlot(QString)'))
v.show
a.exec
```

(Be kind, this is my very first ruby "program"...)

Comment: I was overjoyed, and then I just saw: "This function was introduced in Qt 4.7", I can only use Qt 4.6 (after some effort of getting it to work!), since the 'latest' QtRuby bindings (2.1.0, updated 2010) only offer compatibility with 4.6. Thanks for your input, much appreciated!

Comment: I've just tried with the sample code I posted, and no problem to be seen (apart from the fact that I don't know Ruby :-) ). qt4-ruby built just fine against Qt 4.7.3 (the only version I have installed).

Comment: That looks quite fine indeed, I guess you're not on Windows, right? I'm having problems getting QtRuby to use the .dlls from Qt 4.7.3 any thoughts on that? Here's a blog post I wrote which describes the (painful) way of installing QtRuby on Windows and making it bind to the supplied 4.6.1 .dlls: http://dr1ku.posterous.com/qt-461-ruby-187-on-win32 . I'd be very interested in knowing how you got QtRuby 2.1.0 to play nice with Qt 4.7.3. Thank you again!

Comment: No, I'm on Linux. Using a Qt4 Ruby .dlls that were created against Qt 4.6 won't work with Qt 4.7. Not sure how easy it would be to build qt4-ruby on Windows - might work since it's cmake based, but I don't have any experience with that.

Comment: Yes, there is an installer which hasn't been updated in quite a while (http://vision.eng.shu.ac.uk/mmvlwiki/index.php/Qt4-QtRuby_installer_for_Microsoft_Windows), it used Qt 4.3. I guess I could try and contact the author to help out the poor developer saps who (still) like their Win32 :) Thanks for the reply, it shall be accepted. I might start a new question regarding the other event ('loading'), not sure if overriding fetchMore is ok.